# Using XSL to print on paper other than A4

Tags: printing, xsl-fo

I need to use XSL to generate a letter and print it to a page that is not A4 size.

I have tried setting page-height & page-width, but this just sets up the working regions and does not include any paper size information. Thus when I view it via Adobe Reader the page dimensions are still A4 size.

In my xsl I currently have the following

```
  <xsl:template name="LAYOUT-SETUP">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page" page-height="55mm" page-width  ="85mm" margin-top="5mm" margin-bottom="4mm" margin-left="3mm" margin-right="3mm">
    <fo:region-body />
    <fo:region-before extent="0mm" region-name="xsl-region-before-first"/>
    <fo:region-after extent="0mm"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the right simple-page-master in your page-sequence? The `page-height` and `page-width` attributes do specify the media height/width and should work. What processor are you using? I can post a working example if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you struck anywhere to identify correct page... Have a look on some examples how to define page setup of FO in http://www.learn-xsl-fo-tutorial.com/Page-Layout.cfm#h1.1